# data visualization on a lattice grid

Tags: graphics

Is it possible to visualize an array whose elements are angles as actual angles on a lattice grid? E.g., say, if the input is:

```
{{0, π, π}, {0, 0, π/2}, {π/2, 0, 3 π/3}}
```

then the graphical visualization of this array would be a 3x3 square lattice grid. On each node of the lattice, there will be an arrow (say, inside a circle) which shows the corresponding value from the array. In the above input, this would mean that the arrow at the first lattice-node would be 0, the second would be π, the third would be π, the fourth (i.e., the first node in the second raw of the lattice grid) would be 0, fifth 0, sixth π/2, etc.

Answer (score 15):

It seems natural to convert each number into an arrow (representing a *bearing*, not an angle) by mapping an arrow-making function over the array.  Placing the result into a `GraphicsGrid` provides options to visualize the lattice if desired.

```
angles = {{0, π, π}, {0, 0, π/2}, {π/2, 0, 3 π/3}};
GraphicsGrid[
 Map[Graphics[{
    LightGray, Circle[{0, 0}, 1], 
    Hue[#/(2 π), .6, .8], Thick, Arrowheads[Medium], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Cos[#], Sin[#]}}]}] &, 
  angles, {2}]
```

[image: Picture]

Make it fancier, if you like, by souping up the arguments to `Graphics`.  Here I have added another graphical element, hue, to assist in the visual discrimination.

---

As other answers accumulate it is apparent some explanation of this one may be helpful. When the matrix is small, there's not much objectionable to using complex, highly-decorated, or garish (saturated, heavily painted) graphics: *chacun a son gout.* For larger matrices, though, the point to replacing values with "glyphs," such as arrows, is to be able to *visualize patterns.* Cleveland *et al.*, Tufte, MacEachren, and many others have shown through theory and experiment how to create effective visualizations: that is, ones that are accurately, quickly, and quantitatively interpreted. Their principles more or less amount to *removing* inessential material (Tufte's data-ink ratio maximization principle is explicit about this) and representing the numbers using effective graphic symbolization.  The method offered in this answer is intended to show how to create effective visualizations on larger data quickly.  To see the possibilities, I offer this variation of the problem applied to a larger matrix:

```
angles = 2 π ImageData[ImageAdjust[Blur[RandomImage[1, {40, 25}], 8], 4]];
GraphicsGrid[
 Map[Graphics[{Hue[#/(2 π), .6, .8], Thin, Arrowheads[Small], 
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Cos[#], Sin[#]}}]}] & , angles, {2}]];
Rasterize[%, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: grid of arrows]

Comment: All, thanks a lot for the quick responses! Both the solutions seem quite nice! However, when I obtain these graphics in Mathematica, I can't get the "Save Image As..." option. I want to save these graphics as PDF files. Do you know how one could do so?

Comment: @dbm that's strange, have you tried selecting the cell and go to the _File_ menu option and select from there the choice "save selection as ..."?

Comment: @dbm, One trick is to apply `Rasterize` to the `GraphicsGrid` command: this converts it into an image that can be selected *in toto* and saved to a file.

Comment: @dbm Is this a bug? With a normal `Graphics`, `Plot` etc. output you can right-click and "Save Graphics As...", with a `GraphicsGrid` output you can't do that. But you can select cell bracket on the right and do "Save Selection As...". You've got to delete Out[...]= on the left though, or it will be in the output too.

Comment: @dbm Or, you can always `Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "out.pdf", %]` for instance.

Comment: Biutiful last example.

Comment: FWIW, the technique here is effectively the same procedure applied for graphically displaying a *circular* time series. As Tufte might say, one would like to keep the "chart junk" to a complete minimum, so I think this is the best depiction among all the answers. (Sadly, I cannot give two upvotes.)

Comment: It does seem like a bug (I am using Mathematica 7.2) to me. Selecting the cell and using Save Selection As... option works fine. Export[ ... ] option should also work fine. But it would be great if I could do a right-click and then save it as a pdf. But, anyway, I thank you all a lot for your so kind help.

Comment: +1 for the large matrix example. I see you take the problem for different intended use from mine. And it seems OP is using 7.2, makes my `AngularGauge` approach inapplicable :(

Comment: +1 from me.  Always nice to come across another devote of Tufte.  It makes me optimistic that given enough time (and gentle promotion) we can find way to visualize the increasing complexity of the world in which we live.

Answer (score 10):

There is a [new function `AngularGauge` in *Mathematica 9*](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AngularGauge.html), which might fit your requirement exactly.

```
chartFunc[num_] := AngularGauge[num, {0, 2 π},
  ScaleOrigin -> {0, 2 π},
  LabelStyle -> None,
  TicksStyle -> GrayLevel[.3],
  ScaleDivisions -> {36, 5},
  GaugeMarkers -> "ShinyHubNeedle",
  GaugeFrameElementFunction -> ({} &),
  ScaleRanges -> Partition[
    Append[Riffle[
      Partition[Range[0, 2 π, π/6], 2, 1],
      {{-.05, 0}, {-.1, 0}}], {-0.1, 0}],
    2, 2],
  ScaleRangeColorFunction -> (Lighter[ColorData["Rainbow"][#]] &)
  ]

Map[chartFunc, {{0, π, π}, {0, 0, π/2}, {π/2, 0, 3 π/3}}, {2}] // Grid
```

[image: chartFunc]

You can change the `GaugeMarkers` option to get many other kinds of needles.

## Edit

As the code above is how I understand OP's question, that OP might actually want some fancy indicators which are *not quantitative but qualitative*, inspired by [whuber's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23899/17), and noticed that OP is using *Mathematica 7.2*, here is another built-in function [`ListVectorPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListVectorPlot.html), which is first introduced in version 7, for the required purpose:

```
chartFunc2[data_, size_] := ListVectorPlot[
  Map[{Cos[#], Sin[#]} &, Reverse[data]\[Transpose], {2}],
  VectorColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n},
    Hue[
     If[vy < .5, 1 - #, #] &[ArcCos[2 vx - 1]/(2 π)],
     .6, .8]],
  VectorStyle -> "CircleArrow",
  VectorScale -> {size, 1, None},
  VectorPoints -> All,
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Usage:

```
chartFunc2[{{0, π, π}, {0, 0, π/2}, {π/2, 0, 3 π/3}}, .3]
```

[image: chartFunc2 original array]

```
angles = 2 π ImageData[ImageAdjust[Blur[RandomImage[1, {40, 25}], 8], 4]];
chartFunc2[angles, .015]
```

[image: chartFunc2 large array]

Comment: That's very pretty. To my eye, though, the crucial information--the orientation represented by each number--is lost within the decorative elements.

Comment: @whuber That's how I understand OP's question, in case what OP wants are actually some fancy indicators which are not quantitative but qualitative. btw you can always use different settings for `GaugeMarkers`, `ScaleRanges`, etc for a clearer appearance.

Comment: Everybody is using the same random image (sort of). :D

Comment: @whuber The angular data *is* colored. But arrows could be dropped perhaps.

Answer (score 7):

First you have to define a function that will create the arrow inside the circle for every given angle:

```
arr[th_] := Show[PolarPlot[1, {θ, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Red, Axes -> None], 
                 Graphics[{Blue, Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0}, Normalize[{Cos[th], Sin[th]}]}]}]]
```

then, using `Map` you apply that function to each coefficient of the matrix :

```
Map[arr, {{0, π, π}, {0, 0,π/2}, {π/2, 0, 3π/3}}, {2}]//TableForm
```

> [image]

---

Following David Carraher's comment, if you want angles you can use the function

```
arr2[th_] := PieChart[{Mod[th, 2 π/(2 π), (2 π - Mod[th, 2 π])/(2 π)},
                      ChartStyle -> {Cyan, LightGray}, SectorOrigin -> 0]
```

Now,

```
Map[arr2, {{0, π, π}, {0, 0,π/2}, {π/2, 0, 3π/3}}, {2}]//TableForm
```

> [image]

and combining both:

```
arr3[th_] := Show[PieChart[{Mod[th, 2 π]/(2 π), (2 π - Mod[th, 2 π])/(2 π)}, ChartStyle -> {Cyan, LightGray}, SectorOrigin -> 0,    
                  ChartStyle -> Graphics[{Blue, Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}]],   
           Graphics[{{Blue, Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Cos[th], Sin[th]}}]}, 
           {Blue, Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}}]]

Map[arr3, {{0, π, π}, {0, 0,π/2}, {π/2, 0, 3π/3}}, {2}]//TableForm
```

> [image]

Comment: You have  only drawn a single arm.  To display an angle, one needs two arms and a symbol to show the sweep from one arm to the other.

Comment: I'm sure you merely forgot, but `Normalize[{Cos[th], Sin[th]}]` is *redundant*, you see... you know, because $\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x=1$?

Comment: @DavidCarraher the OP mentions an  arrow inside a circle but its a good idea.

Comment: @J.M. it depends on what the first version of the command was. For instance if the initial plan was to use {1,Tan[th]} to give an example. But I think I will leave it for anyone that cares for a short 101 in trigonometry.

Answer (score 7):

`MapIndexed` gives coordinates for drawing on a single canvas.

```
disks[angles_List] :=
 Graphics[MapIndexed[{
     Orange, Disk[#2, .3],
     Blue, Disk[#2, .3, {0, #1}]} &, angles, {2}]]

disks[{{0, Pi, Pi}, {0, 0, Pi/2}, {Pi/2, 0, 3 Pi/3}}]
```

[image: angels1]

```
disks[RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, {3, 3}]]
```

[image: angels2]

---

Following @whuber, and using a built-in function:

```
angles = 2 Pi ImageData[
    ImageAdjust[Blur[RandomImage[1, {40, 25}], 8], 4]];

ListVectorPlot[
 Map[{Cos[#], Sin[#]} &, Transpose@angles, {2}],
 VectorPoints -> All,
 VectorScale -> .02,
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: vector plot]

Comment: +1 for using a single `Graphics` expression

Comment: The `ListVectorPlot` is good insofar as it addresses this particular question (+1). However, it is more difficult to generalize to other glyphs (which can acquire myriad shapes and characteristics, such as [Chernoff faces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_face)) than your original solution, which is why I think your first approach should be favored.

Comment: I was wondering if someone would use `ListVectorPlot`. +1

Comment: All,
The plots look awesome! I have a very related question and I don't know if I should put a new question for it. The question is: how would you color the same plot according to some function of angles at each node. Say, at the node [i,j], I want to compute a function f[i,j] (to be more specific, f[i_,j_]:=Cos[angles[[i + 1, j]] - angles[[i, j]]]; with all angles[[n+1,i_]]:=angles[[1,i]] and angles[[i_,n+1]]:=angles[[i,1]], i.e., the boundary conditions)? In all the above codes, Hue is used for the angles themselves but extracting the nearby angles seems more involved?

Comment: @dbm I think you could and should update the question with this follow up problem. This way it will show top on the front page (of active questions) and come to everybody's attention.

Comment: @dbm Your `f` here doesn't seem to need periodic boundaries for column index `j`, only for `i`. Anyway, you can achieve this easily in M.

Comment: @BoLe, thanks for your suggestion. I have now posted a new question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24020/coloring-with-hue-for-a-function-on-a-lattice-grid

Also, yes, you are correct. The actual function which also requires boundary conditions in both directions is showed in the new question.
Thanks!