# Coloring with Hue for a function on a lattice grid

Tags: graphics

I wish to color a 2-dimensional lattice grid according to the value of a function at each lattice-node.
More specifically, if I have 9 angles in a 3x3 array,

```
angles={{0, π, π}, {0, 0, π/2}, {π/2, 0, 3 π/3}}
```

then one can plot these angles on a lattice-grid by the following code in Mathematica:

```
angles = {{0, π, π}, {0, 0, π/2}, {π/2, 0, 3 π/3}};
GraphicsGrid[
 Map[Graphics[{
    LightGray, Circle[{0, 0}, 1], 
    Hue[#/(2 π), .6, .8], Thick, Arrowheads[Medium], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Cos[#], Sin[#]}}]}] &, 
  angles, {2}]]
```

Here, the colouring is done using the Hue command according to the value of each angle. However, now I want to compute a function `f[i,j]`; to be more specific,

```
f[i_,j_]:=Cos[angles[[i + 1, j]] - angles[[i, j]]] + Cos[angles[[i, j+1]] - angles[[i, j]]];
```

with

```
angles[[n+1,i_]]:=angles[[1,i]];
angles[[i_,n+1]]:=angles[[i,1]];
```

i.e., the boundary conditions.

In the first code, Hue is used with the `angles[[i,j]]` (through `#`), which is probably straightforward. But is it possible to use `f[i,j]` instead, where `f[i,j]` is defined as above?

P.S. This question is related to: [data visualization on a lattice grid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23895/data-visualization-on-a-lattice-grid)

Thanks!

### dbm

P.S. The final code, thanks to BoLe's answers:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
n := 10
angles = Table[RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}], {i, n}, {j, n}];
f[here_, down_, right_] := Cos[down - here] + Cos[right - here]
g[list_, {i_, j_}] := 
 Module[{m, n}, {m, n} = Dimensions[list]; {list[[i, j]], 
   If[i != m, list[[i + 1, j]], -list[[1, j]]], 
   If[j != n, list[[i, j + 1]], -list[[i, 1]]]}]
GraphicsGrid[
 MapIndexed[
  Graphics[{LightGray, Circle[{0, 0}, 1], 
     Hue[Rescale[f @@ g[angles, #2], {-2, 2}, {0, 1}]], Thin, 
     Arrowheads[Small], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Cos[#], Sin[#]}}]}] &, 
  angles, {2}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Define `f` and apply it to every element of the matrix (that becomes three elements). `Mod` ensures periodic boundaries.

```
f[here_, down_, right_] := Cos[down - here] + Cos[right - here]

MapIndexed[
 f @@ Extract[angles,
    Mod[{#2, #2 + {1, 0}, #2 + {0, 1}}, 3, 1]] &,
 angles, {2}]
```

**Replying to first comment.**

```
(* @whuber example *)
angles = 2 Pi ImageData[
    ImageAdjust[Blur[RandomImage[1, {20, 10}], 8], 4]];

GraphicsGrid[Map[Graphics[{
     Gray, Thin, Arrowheads[Small],
     Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Cos[#], Sin[#]}}]}] &, angles, {2}]]
```

[image: grid]

Coloring according to f, which can be between -2 and 2 I think, rescaled to 0-to-1 for `Hue`.

```
GraphicsGrid[MapIndexed[Graphics[{
     Hue[Rescale[
       f @@ Extract[angles,
         Mod[{#2, #2 + {1, 0}, #2 + {0, 1}}, 3, 1]],
       {-2, 2}, {0, 1}]],
     Thin, Arrowheads[Small],
     Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Cos[#], Sin[#]}}]}] &, angles, {2}]]
```

[image: grid2]

**Replying to fourth comment:** One way to code custom boundary conditions is to define a custom extraction function and place it in place of `Extract`.

```
g[list_, {i_, j_}] := Module[{m, n},
  {m, n} = Dimensions[list]; {
   list[[i, j]],
   If[i != m, list[[i + 1, j]], -list[[1, j]]],
   If[j != n, list[[i, j + 1]], -list[[i, 1]]]}]

GraphicsGrid[MapIndexed[Graphics[{
     Hue[Rescale[f @@ g[angles, #2], {-2, 2}, {0, 1}]],
     Thin, Arrowheads[Small],
     Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Cos[#], Sin[#]}}]}] &, angles, {2}]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not particularly interested in the function itself which I could have easily coded up. The thing is, I want to color the arrows according to the values of f at each site. i.e., instead of Hue[#/(2Pi)] in the main code, I want to insert something like Hue[F[[i,j]]]. Sorry for not explaining the question well enough.

Comment: @dbm, you might want to take note of the fact that most of the coloring functions only accept arguments within the interval $[0,1]$ (well, `Hue[]` is periodic, but its primary domain is still $[0,1)$). Your `f` doesn't seem to have the correct scaling. Maybe you should specify your desired coloring function...

Comment: @dbm See, I merely inserted the f-@@-applying lines from above for coloring. Feel modular. :>

Comment: @BoLe, The edited comment is almost what I wanted, except that it would be great if the rescaling is [-1,1] for the function. Yes, the function has random [-2,2]. I can just divide the function by 2, and hence it gets rescaled to [-1,1].
Moreover, I would still prefer to have boundary conditions explicitly defined as I also wish to use anti-periodic boundary conditions, i.e., angles[[i_,n+1]]:= -angles[[i,1]] and angles[[n+1,i_]]:= -angles[[1,i]].

Btw, could we put the Circles around the arrows back?

Comment: @dbm I reckon you are able enough to mix all the offered code into something with circles. ;-) As for the custom boundary conditions ... you could always `If` the code.

Comment: @BoLe, Thanks! I have now put the final version of the code below the question, if anyone cares in the future.
Just final query about this code: What is the interpretation of each colour? I mean how does Mathematica decide which colour to pick. Does it first take, say angles[[1,1]], then compute the function f at the point [[1,1]], picks a colour. Then goes over [[1,2]], again computes f, and if the value of f is the same as that at [[1,1]], then assigns the same colour otherwise a new colour. Is this correct?

Comment: @dbm, there really isn't an "if" to speak of in BoLe's code; after computing `f` and rescaling the range $[-2,2]$ to $[0,1]$, this scaled value is then used to pick a color from the usual color wheel, via `Hue[]`.

Comment: @J.M., in that case, BoLe's code probably doesn't help too much. I am looking for a code which does what I explained in my previous comment.

Comment: @dbm, hmm, alright. Is `f[]` just the cosine of the angle, or something more elaborate?

Comment: @J.M., Its is just cosine of the angles. I just want two boundary conditions on angles, periodic and anti-periodic. Other than that, nothing more elaborate than that.

Comment: @dbm Yes, `If` would come into play in custom element extractions, see edit.

Comment: @dbm About coloring, `f` is evaluated with the three elements (*ij* and its two neighbors), this value is fed to `Hue`, yet just before rescaled from its domain `[-2, 2]` to `[0, 1]` -- which `Hue` represent as rainbow shades red, orange, yellow, ... and back to red. You might want to color it differently.

Comment: @Bole, Great! I have edited the code in the Question section as well. That's precisely I wanted now. Although it would be great if Hue (or any other option) is scaled from [-1,1] because the current code doesn't distinguish the function values of -1, 0 and 1, for example, unfortunately.

Comment: @dbm Wait, your `f` takes values `[-2, 2]` which are rescaled/transformed to `[0, 1]`. So `-1` to `0.25` I think, `0` to `0.5`, `1` to `0.75`. From these `Hue` produces different shades.

Comment: @BoLe, sorry, yes it is rescaled to [0,1].
Is there any way to have -1 to 1 scaling for the colouring purposes in Mathematica? Does Matlab or other packages have such feature?